# Can you paginate bootstrap layouts grid column?

Tags: vue.js, pagination, bootstrap-vue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8ula.png)

My question is I want to show 4 column of image with 2 rows per pagination but for bootstrap pagination it only seem to work on list and table.

Comment: have you tried to loop images into class="col-3" block? I don't see any problem to loop 8 images in any type of blocks

Comment: I already did but when I try to use pagination in https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/pagination it seem to work only with table or list.

Answer (score 0):

Just got it working out now. The paginate that BootstrapeVue Provide only work for table and list.So you have to write it down by yourself.